# EFCore codefirst migrations and the aspnetcore_environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I've been using workarounds for a while for this issue, but figured I'd ask online and see if anyone has any hints or alternate methods for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a very basic core 3.1 MVC setup that has setting files like this:

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

#### appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

#### appsettings.Local.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=new-test-site;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

and in the `launchsettings.json` I have a couple of profiles setup like so:

```
 "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "new_test_site_local": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      }
    },
    "new_test_site_dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

So in my mind, when I use the PMC to set `$aspnetcore_environment="Local"` that should allow my project to run with the `appsettings.Local.json` (e.g. the connection string) values taking precedence.

But it doesn't seem to do that? I can only get it to work if I copy-paste that "local" connection string into the `dev` or "normal" appsettings.

How can I run commands like `add-migration` and `update-database` with my local settings as the target?!

Comment: The default host configuration should work? (source https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c0db07b3f3f093b5f4cd27e1f5e8aa54adad049d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L210) How are you building your host? Command line tools will use the environment variables set in the console, so `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local` ? Is it case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PowerShell syntax for setting environment variables:

```
$env:aspnetcore_environment="Local"
```

Comment: I've tried, and I check it's set to "Local" in the PMC with `$aspnetcore_environment` - it returns "Local" so it's definitely set - but then when I try to run `add-migration` (which doesn't even need a connection at this point) it seems to default to one of the other `appsettings.json` files. Very annoying.

Comment: Note that without `env:` you're just setting a session-scoped PowerShell variable, not an environment variable. ASP.NET Core doesn't know about PowerShell variables--only environment variables.

Comment: Arggghhh OK - that's done it, thanks for the explanation. I hadn't even realised I was missing the "env" portion and when I had, I thought that it was just for powershell! And I KNEW I'd had this all working at some point in the past. I will never forget this!